# bootstrap-vue's grid system breaking after navigation with b-list-group-item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using nuxt.js with bootstrap-vue and the grid system breaks when I use nuxt-link to navigate on my website.
Basically what happens is when I put the the URL directly on the browser, something like 'localhost:3000/contato', it works just fine. However, if I use `<b-list-group-item to="/contato">Contato</b-list-group-item>` the css just breaks entirely.

**What it should look like?** https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9UCN.png Note: that's how it looks after refreshing the page with the "wrong css"

**What is it looking like using `<b-list-group-item to="/contato">Contato</b-list-group-item>`?** https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMPvf.png

Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <b-container>
    <b-row align-h="between" cols="1" cols-lg="2" cols-sm="1" class="mt-4">
      <b-col align-self="center">
        <b-img
          center
          style="max-height: 200px;"
          src="https://www.dovercourt.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/610-6104451_image-placeholder-png-user-profile-placeholder-image-png.jpg"
        />
        <p style="text-align: center">{{ artist.name }}</p>
      </b-col>
      <b-col align-self="center">
        <p id="description_text" class="text-justify" style="width: 100%">
          {{ artist.description_text }}
        </p>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <b-row cols="1" cols-lg="3" cols-sm="1">
      <b-col>
        <InstagramEmbed :url="artist.url1" />
      </b-col>
      <b-col>
        <InstagramEmbed :url="artist.url2" />
      </b-col>
      <b-col>
        <InstagramEmbed :url="artist.url3" />
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
import InstagramEmbed from 'vue-instagram-embed'

export default {
  components: {
    InstagramEmbed
  },
  data() {
    return {
      artist: this.$store.state.artistas.artistas.find(
        (x) => x.id === parseInt(this.$route.params.id)
      )
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

I tried to put text where the 'InstagramEmbed' components are but I still got the same result.

I tried all the routing components available and still got the same result.

I have a sidebar to navigate between the pages that I can toggle with a button on the navbar. Here is the sidebar:

```
<template>
  <div class="mt-2">
    <b-button
      id="sidebar-button"
      v-b-toggle.sidebar-1
      style="background-color: #561b1f; color: #f3a40c;"
    >
      &#x2B24;
    </b-button>

    <b-sidebar id="sidebar-1" title="" shadow>
      <div class="px-3 py-2">
        <b-list-group>
          <b-list-group-item to="/contato">Contato</b-list-group-item>
        </b-list-group>
      </div>
    </b-sidebar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: Update your code with nuxt-link for example

Comment: Looks like you're closing your link incorrect `<nuxt-link/>` should be `</nuxt-link>`

Comment: updated the answer to be more specific. thanks for the advice!